# How do I make a randomized order of the array modifier?

Tags: modifiers

I'm trying to make a line of colored bubbles using an array modifier but I want them in a sort of unorganized conga line. Is it possible using the array modifier, or do I have to do them manually?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this by using a *Particle System*. Simply add in a plane, go to the *Particles* tab, and follow the directions:

- With the plane selected, add a new particle system by pressing *New*
- Set the number of particles to something lower, like 10
- Set the *End* frame to 1 (make sure the *Start* frame is also 1)

Picture Representation 1/3:

[image]

Further down the settings:

- Under the *Physics* tab, select *No*. This will turn off gravity.
- Under the *Render* tab, set the emitter to *Object*, then by clicking the box, select the object you want to array/duplicate (in your case, the bubbles)

Picture Representation 2/3:

[image]

Optional:

- If you don't like the randomization of the particles, set the *Seed*
  to a different number.

Picture Representation 3/3:

[image]

You can hide the plane by putting it on a separate Render Layer or by assigning it an invisible material.

EDIT: You can also put the particles on a line by scaling down the plane on the Y axis. If you want it on a different axis, you can just rotate the plane. And finally, if you want it on a curve, simply just replace the plane with a curve.

Comment: I actually want them on a line, but I think that could work. Thanks. :)

Comment: Yep! Also, you can put it on a line by scaling down the plane on the Y axis. If you want it on a different axis, you can just rotate the plane. And finally, if you want it on a curve, simply just replace the plane with a curve (I added this to my answer).